# How to resize the image before saving in Android

Tags: android

I want to save image in a directory, but before I save it I want to reduce the size of the image as I need to Upload it later. How can I resize the image and save it?

```
private static File saveImage(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {

        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }  else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

is there any library or inbuilt function to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the image and resize it.See [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) and you can use [decodeFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) to load the image and resize it with [BitmapOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize), and Bitmap class has a method to save the scaled image to disk. See [compress](http://eveloper.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))